# Read a struct with BinaryReader.read in C# for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm converting legacy C# code to Unity 2017, and I'm stuck on methods to read binary data to a large struct.

I have the following struct defined :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Header
{
    public readonly int Magic;
    public readonly int Version;
    public readonly int FieldA;
    public readonly int FieldB;
    // ...
}
```

and the following code from my legacy C# application :

```
using (var strm = new FileStream(mFileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
    var reader = new BinaryReader(strm);
    mHeader = reader.Read<Header>(); // <-- error here
    }
```

The error message is : `The non-generic method 'BinaryReader.Read()' cannot be used with typed arguments`

I guess that a workaround could be to use a bunch of `reader.Read()` calls, but the header struct is rather large and I'd like to find a way to use what looks like a good shortcut and keep the code simpler and smaller.

Comment: That `Read<T>()` method is custom code.  It has never been part of the framework.  It's probably an extension method, and if so, just copy it.

Comment: Well, where may I find it ? I didn't see anything in the file defining the Header struct, so any hint for finding this code ? (I'm a C# newbie as you can see)

Comment: In the original code, click somewhere on "Read", then hit F12 or right click it and go to implementation.

Comment: The original code is not in an IDE which I could use, but with your help, I finally manage to find an `Extensions.cs` containing the Read method. Many thanks !!!

Comment: That works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Read() method is custom code. It has never been part of the framework. It's probably an extension method, and if so, just copy it.

You can find it by clicking somewhere on "Read", then hit F12 or right click it and go to implementation